# Compose Android - How to refresh a list which holds some data without complete list refresh

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

Use Case :
I have a list(User Profile) of items loaded using LazyItem , now I need to update an item in the view (i.e) just some Last Active time for every second . I have tried by using the LaunchedEffect from coroutine scope, based on the value change I made some actions, Launched effect triggers on each second but the mutableState value action is not triggered. Suggest me a way to make the refresh for each second

```
var userActiveTime = remember {  mutableStateOf(false) }
var LocalContext = LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(Unit) 
{
        while(true){
            delay(1000)
            userActiveTime.value = true
        }
    }


if(userActiveTime.value){
        Toast.makeText(LocalContext,"called${Date().time}",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
```

Note : The above block is not triggered

Comment: The code does not compile. a) there's no checkLaunchEffect variable b) LocalContext is called wrong.

Comment: @m.reiter , its just local context which holds the context, anyhow I have updated the code and I have found the solution as the boolean value was once made true and remains the same hence the block was not triggered . Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use crutches in the form of 1-second updates. Usually you update the whole list and pass it to LazyList. If you are afraid that it will affect optimization, you should add keys to LazyList. With them, LazyList will understand which Item to update when your list is updated. And LazyList will automatically update its items when your list is updated, so you don't need to make a timer with a 1 second delay.
Learn more about keys and how to implement them here:
[Lists and grids](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#item-keys)

In this guide you can find out how to optimize LazyList in details

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if the data that I need to update is from server then updating the whole list by lazy makes sense, but my need is all based on local instead of page refresh... By updating lazyList won't affect the whole UI to recreate ?

Comment: Not if you have a well-constructed ui. 
Check this [article](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model)

Shortly: Compose Runtime skips composables which doesn't changed